# Is there a rough timeline for Breeze server to support asp.net 5 / ef7?

Tags: breeze

Do you have any sort of timeline, however rough it may be, when we can expect breeze server to support asp.net 5 and ef7?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET 5 is being renamed to ASP.NET Core 1 and Entity Framework 7 is being renamed to Entity Framework Core 1 and the latest version will be RC1. At this date/time the proccess is ongoing.
Hope Breeze team will communicate and be at this rendez-vous.

Comment: thanks @M.Ouedraogo for your input... i was hoping a response from the breeze guys but i guess not... :)... yes i understand that changes taking place... i believe even before the name change the version was already rc1... that's the only reason i have taken notice and have begun experimenting to provide feedback to my company... we currently use breeze and like it... but this has given me the opportunity to look at alternatives... didn't realize there were so many... thank you

Comment: There is more information about this here from Ward Bell:  https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/248992-3-breeze-server-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6958216-compatibility-of-breeze-server-webapi2-with-asp-vn